# CSV Text file parser with TextFieldParser - MalformedLineException

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I am working on a CSV parser using C# [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.

My CSV data is deliminated by `,` and the string is enclosed by a `"` character.

However, sometimes the data row cell can also have a `"` which appears to be making the parser throw an exception.

[image]

This is my C# code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

namespace CSV_Parser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Init
            string CSV_File = "test.csv";

            // Proceed If File Is Found
            if (File.Exists(CSV_File))
            {
                // Test
                Parse_CSV(CSV_File);
            }

            // Finished
            Console.WriteLine("Press any to exit ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Parse_CSV(String Filename)
        {
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(Filename))
            {
                parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                parser.SetDelimiters(",");
                parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fieldRow = parser.ReadFields();
                    foreach (string fieldRowCell in fieldRow)
                    {
                        // todo
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the content of my `test.csv` file:

```
" dummy test"s data",   b  ,  c  
d,e,f
gh,ij
```

What is the best way to deal with `"` in my row cell data?

---

**UPDATE**

Based on `Tim Schmelter's` answer, I have modified my code to the following:

```
static void Parse_CSV(String Filename)
{
    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(Filename))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
        while (parser.PeekChars(1) != null)
        {
            var cleanFieldRowCells = parser.ReadFields().Select(
                f => f.Trim(new[] { ' ', '"' }));

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" | ", cleanFieldRowCells));
        }
    }
}
```

Which appears to produce the following (correctly):

[image]

Is this is the best way to deal with string enclosed by quotes, having quotes?

Comment: preprocess the file to make sure it is well formed.

Comment: Did you try with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: What happens if you try to remove the quoting character. So set `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` to `false`.

Comment: @Steve - Doesn't that flag simply tells the parser that the string enclosed using double quotes? I believe this is turned on by default.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's not really corrupted. We expect data like this. E.g. one cell could have this data: `"11" Wide"` and i need to be able to parse this...

Comment: @Latheesan: it is broken according to spec (RFC 4180): >> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
       appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
       another double quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you omit the quoting-character by setting `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` to `false`?

```
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(@"Path"))
{
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;
    parser.Delimiters = new[]{","};
    while(parser.PeekChars(1) != null)
    {
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
    }
}
```

You can  remove the quotes manually:

```
var cleanFields = fields.Select(f => f.Trim(new[]{ ' ', '"' }));
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, using your idea, I have modified the code slightly to achieve what I wanted, see first post updated. Is this the best way to go about parsing string enclosed with quotes, having quotes?

Comment: @LatheesanKanes: at least it is the only way i know. Imho your file is corrupt, fields should not contain quoting characters, otherwise either the field should be cleaned first or a different quoting character should be used. So this apporach is just a way to fix a corrupt file.