# Regular expression pattern. Get fields from string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I can not write a regular expression pattern

string:

```
25,4.6,4%,32,"text1","text2, text3","text4,,t"
```

result array:

```
25 |
4.6 |
4% |
32 |
"text1" |
"text2, text3" |
"text4,,t" |
```

Comment: Regular expressions will not help you here as you're dealing with quoted strings, you'll need to write a state-machine parser instead.

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403194/split-using-delimiter-except-when-delimiter-is-escaped

Comment: [Stop rolling your own CSV parser](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble)

Answer (score 1):

I would not use regex (or `String.Split`) to parse CSV but an available csv-parser. The [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) is the only parser which is already built-in .NET. You can use it also in C#:

```
string csv = "25,4.6,4%,32,\"text1\",\"text2, text3\",\"text4,,t\"";
var reader = new StringReader(csv);

List<string[]> allLineFields = new List<string[]>();
using (var parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(reader))
{
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true; // <--- !!!
    string[] fields;
    while ((fields = parser.ReadFields()) != null)
    {
        allLineFields.Add(fields);
    }
}
foreach (string[] arr in allLineFields)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", arr));
```

Output: `25|4.6|4%|32|text1|text2, text3|text4,,t`

Of course there are other available parsers like this: [A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)

Answer (score 0):

RegEx is not the way to go with this because it isn't designed to handle quoted strings well (or balancing paranthesis).

However, it looks like your data is CSV. If this is true, .NET has a [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) that parses CSV (including quotes).

You will have to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in your project to use this.

Look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297562/csv-text-file-parser-with-textfieldparser-malformedlineexception) for an example using C# and quoted values.